# Getting unpredictable issue in QTP

Tags: qtp

I'm trying to automate some web application using QTP and I have automated most of the modules. But in one module I'm facing an unpredictable issue that when we click the record hyperlink manually it fetches 3 rows of data, but it doesn't fetch any record when we do the same through QTP scripts.

Can some one help me on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the application is listening to an event that QTP doesn't replay.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455924/3848) on how to use Device Replay to solve this problem.