# How to perform Right Click on an object using SendKeys in UFT?

Tags: object, testing, automation, qtp, sendkeys

I want to perform a **Right Click** on an object in my Application Under Test but I am not able to perform this action. Is there any way to do it using **sendkeys**?

Comment: What technology is your AUT?

Comment: My Application Under Test is on Web

Answer (score 0):

In Web, if the `RightClick` operation doesn't achieve the expected results this may be because UFT doesn't fire the sequence of events that the browser is expecting. You can tell UFT to run Web tests using device replay in which case it will move the mouse cursor to the correct location and simulate actual mouse clicks (including right-click).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455924/3848), or just do the following:

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2 ' change to device replay mode
' Perform your right-click here
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1 ' back to normal
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways.

1) By **Object.Click**

like   ObjSomeObject.Click 1,1,micRightButton

2) By **Mercury Device Replay**

For This Get **abs_x** And **abs_y**,**Height,Width** properties. calculate them and derive **intDerivedxLocation** AND intDerivedxLocation. Then perform following

intabsX = objApp.getRoProperty("abs_x")

intabsY = objApp.getRoProperty("abs_y")

intHeight = objApp.getRoProperty("height")

intWidth = objApp.getRoProperty("width")

intDerivedxLocation= Cint(intabsX) +Cint(intWidth /2)

intDerivedxLocation= Cint(intabsY) +Cint(intHeight/2)

Dim objMercuryDeviceReplay

Set objMercuryDeviceReplay= CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")

objMercuryDeviceReplay.MouseClick intDerivedxLocation, intDerivedxLocation, 2

Answer (score 0):

there is one shortcut for Keyboard right click Shift+F10.
If we pass this through send keys then we can able to do this.before doing this we have to either mouse over on that object or we have make that active by clicking on that object.

for Example

```
Browser().page().webelement().click;
Browser().page().webelement().sendkeys "+F10";
```